# express.js res.redirect with masking

Tags: node.js, express, url-masking

In express.js, can I use `res.redirect` while performing masking.

Example, my app is at `http://example.com`. I want `http://example.com/test` to redirect to `http://google.com` while keeping the URL as `http://example.com/test`.

In other words, the user sees google's landing-page while URL == `http://example.com/test`.

Comment: Do you want the google url to be mask even after the user makes a search or click a link on the page ?

Comment: no. only the first time he gets on it.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do then is to get the Google's HTML code and send it in your response like this :

```
var request = require('request'); // https://github.com/mikeal/request

function (html) {
  return request.get('http://www.google.com', (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      return body;
    }
  });
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.send(html);
};
```

Since this is a automated translation from CoffeeScript, things might need to be polished, but the idea is there.

Comment: the only problem with this is that you need to check for broken links and whatnot. if all of their links are absolute and not relative, then i think this is a very viable solution.

Comment: So the idea is that i get google's html, and render it on my page. What would happen if the google.com page contains js, for instance, a backbone app?

Comment: We are talking about google.com, not gmail.com. That would be a completely other solution.